# Adjust page margins for note page with beamer

Tags: beamer, margins, notes

I have to rebuild a PowerPoint template with beamer and one convenient part of my solutions is to set a value for the top margin. Unfortunately this effects the note page as well. Is there a solution to correct the note page margin?

The problem can be solved when using `\restoregeometry` and `\note[itemize]{\item}` after `\end{frame}` but sometimes I want to use something like `\note<2>{}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\geometry{top=4cm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
Test \note<1>{Test note} \note<2>{Second note}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't change the top/bottom geometry margins. Instead make a headline of whatever height you want the top margin to have:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\geometry{top=4cm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right} 

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\rule{0cm}{4cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
Test \note<1>{Test note} \note<2>{Second note}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]